# Build & deploy docker images to Kubernetes from localhost?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I see CI/CD systems like GitLab CI/CD, BitBucket Pipelines, and CodeFresh CI/CD. These look good, but I'm wondering, why not build my container images either on localhost  (then upload the image using `rsync`/`scp`) or build directly on the cluster, and then deploy via kubectl? This would circumvent using a build service and container registry (which I don't want to pay for). For small teams, this seems viable. I realize it's not as nice as using a build service, but aside from that, why not run deployments this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the standard repository setup, you don’t need to give people ssh access to the nodes, and the nodes are fairly replaceable: if a node dies (and even cloud-hosted nodes sometimes need to be replaced) if it can always pull its content from a Docker repository then you don’t need to do any manual work to start a new one up.

At a very very minimum I’d set up (or pay for) a Docker repository (or hosted service: Docker Hub, quay.io, Google’s GCR, Amazon’s ECR, ...) and write a build script that `docker build`s an image, `docker push`es it to somewhere appropriate, updates a Deployment object, and `kubectl apply`s it.  You don’t necessarily *need* a CI system (but you probably want one; again you can buy one in the cloud).

On a non-technical level, if you design and build a deployment sequence that involves hand-running a sequence of commands, especially in a small company, it will become a maintainability problem (you personally will spend a great deal of time running these same commands over and over and will have to fix it if it doesn’t work).

Comment: Ya, I was thinking I would put the commands into script files, but someone pointed out that the image would have to be rsync'd to each node. Does seem like a ton of work to maintain. I'm trying out Codefresh, it seems really good, and the free tier seems quite permissive.